# Webpack doesn't recognize ES6 spread syntax

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Trying to test the ES6 Spread syntax, but webpack gives me an error.

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader', 
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'latest']
                },
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            }
         ]
```

app.jsx (webpack entry file)

```
var objOne = {name: 'Jussi', location: 'Interwebs'};
var objTwo = {
    age: 28, 
    ...objOne
};
```

console

```
webpack
Hash: 2a82a67f90f9aa05ab4a
Version: webpack 1.12.13
Time: 1409ms
    + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in ./app/app.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (7:1)

   5 | var objTwo = {
   6 |  age: 28, 
>  7 |  ...objOne
     |  ^
```

This ellipsis notation should work, right? Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Object spread is not part of the ES2015 specification.

Answer (score 4):

This is not valid ES2015 (or ES2016) code:

```
var objOne = {name: 'Jussi', location: 'Interwebs'};
var objTwo = {
    age: 28, 
    ...objOne
};
```

It relies on [object spread properties](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread), which are a Stage 3 proposal (as of this writing in November 2016). (*Array* spread is part of ES2015, but not object spread.) That means that the feature is fully defined and well fleshed-out, and specification text is ready, but that it's waiting on implementations and implementation feedback. (Details in [the process document](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/).) So it's really far along and likely to make it into a spec soon (perhaps not ES2017, though it may still be possible depending on how far along implementations are, but almost certainly ES2018).

Babel and other similar transpilers will transpile it with the relevant option set (for instance, for Babel it's the [`stage-3` preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/); [example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-3&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20o%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%7D%3B%0Alet%20o2%20%3D%20%7Bc%3A%203%2C%20...o%7D%3B&playground=false)).

Comment: @abhirathore2006: Most people who use React use a transpiler which understands object spread properties (and JSX).

Comment: Good answer, but perhaps emphasize how transpiling is a solution to the problem. The "why it doesn't work" part kind of overshadows the "how to make it work" part. For example just add a header `#Solution` before the last paragraph.